# development 以外にだけインストールしたい Gemfile の書き方

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

rails_same_site_cookie を staging, production だけでいれて
http://localhost:3000 でアクセスする development にはいれたくないです

```
gem "rails_same_site_cookie", group: [:staging, :production]
```

とかいてもローカルで bundle install すると普通に入ってしまいます
development 以外でのみインストールしたい場合どのようにかけばいいのでしょうか

Comment: rails_same_site_cookie の話に立ち返ると、 https://github.com/pschinis/rails_same_site_cookie/issues/20#issuecomment-603897256 で言及されているように development 環境を作る方が便利な気はします。production 環境との環境差異は小さい方が嬉しいだろうからです。

Comment: development 環境は作っていて development だけにいれるのはできるんですが development 以外にだけ入れたいです

Comment: development という namespace を作るという話をしているのではなくて、手元の環境でも動くようにする方が良いのでは、という話です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bundle install時に

```
bundle install --without production staging
```

としてみて下さい。

bundle install時にはどのenvironmentで使うか分からないので、すべてのenvironmentのgemがインストールされるという事だと思います。

一度`--without`を指定すればその情報は`.bundle/config`に記録されて、以降は`bundle install`でも大丈夫になるようです。

Comment: やっぱりそうかくしかないんですね

Comment: この書き方は Bundler 3 から deprecated です。`bundle config --local set without 'production staging'` などと書く方がオススメです。